# Need help in making a reusable widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

So I am making an app with flutter. So in the *main.dart* file i am making a component which is basically a bunch of widgets wrapped together. I have to use this component multiple times so I thought of making these reusable component in another dart file and then importing it in *main.dart*.

This is my code for *reusable.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

double mainTab = 150;

class TileData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TileDataState createState() => _TileDataState();
}

class _TileDataState extends State<TileData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200 - 15.0,
      width: mainTab - 10.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 0, 0),
        child: Column(

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I plan to use this TileData Widget in my *main.dart* in this manner

```
ListView(
   children: children: <Widget>[
      TileData(
          children: <Widget>[
               Text('Element 1'),
]),
      TileData(
          children: <Widget>[
               Text('Element 2'),
]),
      TileData(
          children: <Widget>[
               Text('Element 3'),
],
)
],
),
```

So the children of the TileData() widget are actually the children of the column which was last wrapped in the widget in *reusable.dart*

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TileDate

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

double mainTab = 150;

class TileData extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Widget> widgetsList;
  TileData({this.widgetsList});

  @override
  _TileDataState createState() => _TileDataState();
}

class _TileDataState extends State<TileData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200 - 15.0,
      width: mainTab - 10.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: widget.widgetsList,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:test/widgets/TileData.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2d3447), body: MyApp()),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        TileData(
          widgetsList: [Text("Element 1")],
        ),
        TileData(
          widgetsList: [Text("Element 2")],
        ),
        TileData(
          widgetsList: [Text("Element 3")],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In this way u can reuse

Answer (score 3):

Create a property and use it as an argument in the constructor of the reusable widget.

```
final List<Widget> children;

TileData({this.children});
```

Then, in your build method, pass the property to the column.

```
Column(
  children: widget.children
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListView.builder()`

add Constructor in your `TileData` widget

something like

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount:data.length,
itemBuilder: (context,index){
return TileData(data:"Element $index");
}

)
```